# Usage of words had been and or in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

I have difficulty in understanding how to use "had been" and "or" in a sentence which describes a past tenancy.

Example:

"These questions therefore arise: had the tenancy been extended; or had it been changed hand; or even had there been no tenancy in force at all, at the material time"

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be formal and or legal language.

---

*Some questions arise.*

*Question 1: Had the tenancy been extended?*

*Question 2: Had the tenancy been changed hand?*

*Question 3: Had there been no tenancy at all?*

---

The word "or" is used to show that the above options were alternatives. Presumably only one of the above three is possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help